# Moved bin folder! How to get that back?

Tags: ubuntu

I accidentally moved Bin folder from the root to /usr/local/bin. Now I am not able to open the terminal at all and on the top of it, I powered off the system just to reboot it. Now, it does not boot at all and is stuck in the middle!! any suggestion can be helpful.. Thanks

Comment: Do you have/can you make a live CD of Ubuntu or any other Linux?

Comment: Boot using SystemRescue ( https://www.system-rescue.org/Download/ ), fix the issue. It's quite easy.

Answer (score 1):

In grub append kernel parameter: `init=/usr/local/bin/sh`, then move back the folder to its place.

Comment: From the look of it the correct `init` will be `/usr/local/bin/bin/sh`